# How to gather credit card information

Tags: iphone, ios, credit-card, in-app-billing

I need to charge user for non-digital content inside my application. Are there any free/not free SDK's/libraries to gather credit card information or I should write all the code by myself ? What pitfalls may I encounter ?

Comment: You probably do not want to be responsible for storing credit card info.  Seems like an unnecessary liability.  Use an existing API or service.

Comment: Of course not ! What services or api's you advice ?

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I would use the [paypal api](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries)

Comment: Does it give the possibility to pay not only by using a paypal account, but by filling credit card information ?

Comment: No I don't think so. But you will find it the best "easy" solution.

Comment: Currently, there are means for you to allow only Credit Card Payments using PayPal API, something like a checkout as guest user. You need to specify some parameters to make it the default behavior so that users are first asked to checkout with credit card but still have the options to checkout as a PayPal user. You don't even need any premium account or such stuff from PayPal. but i do think this requires that you have a bank account verified and maybe credit card too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a google engine available named "Tesseract OCR engine" through it you can take the data from the image. You can download it free from the following link:-

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Comment: sorry, maybe I explained my question not good enough, but I don't need to take data from the image

Answer (score 0):

To gather credit card information , You need to contact specific Card Authority like Visa , Mastreo etc. These Authority gives API . Which should be used. This is legal way to fetch data. In Case of Credit Card & Bank Account Dont go for any other non-authorized API .

[CC Avenue](http://www.ccavenue.com/content/quick.jsp)

this is one you can use

Answer (score 0):

Apple won't allow you to implement payment methods natively - you have to either use WebKit and show the page or use Apple's own services.

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jetsetter-for-ipad/id416813861?mt=8

As I understand, in this application after all credit card information is filled, application sends it to a web service and all magick is done there. This is what I need..

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend creating a web service that handle all the transaction, that's what i did.

Comment: Yes, but should I create interface for billing by myself ? And another question is security issues. I.e. after users fills his credit card information, I will be able to steal his card number, secret code, etc. So this is really a bad practice. Please share your experience and explain more detailed how you did this: what api's or services you used.